# Accessing mp3 metadata

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo

I'm working on a music player app and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to read metadata like album cover, artist name etc. from mp3 files. I'm using Expo's MediaLibrary and it doesn't provide the required functionality. I've found some 3rd party packages but they all require me to eject, which I don't want to do.

So is there a way where I can read metadata from mp3 files without ejecting from Expo?

Answer (score 1):

please you do install

```
npm i react-native-get-music-files.
```

For a detailed example, please visit: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-get-music-files

And this installation requires a link, you must use ExpoKit.
How to use it is located on the linked site. https://docs.expo.io/versions/v32.0.0/expokit/eject/

If you have any further questions, please leave a comment.